# nginx reverse proxy or squid forward proxy (transparent)?

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, squid, node.js

I have to implement a proxy server in front of a running production server to route and secure the production-server. On the production server multiple node.js applications listening on different ports.

```
client1.example.com --> ProxyServer --> Application on LiveServer1 at port 3001
client2.example.com --> ProxyServer --> Application on LiveServer1 at port 3002
...
client100.example.com -> ProxyServer --> Application on LiveServer6 at port 3001
```

All subdomains should only be accessible via https and the user should not be noticed of any ssl-certificate problems (man-in-the-middle). I was looking into either using Squid or an nginx. What could you recommend for this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

squid is thought as being a proxy for workstations for example - you need a reverse proxy, so nginx is a good choice, I think.

Answer (score 0):

These days, Nginx is the best option for reverse proxies. Another good option is Varnish. Squid offers a lot of features, but it's purpose is to work as forward-proxy, not reverse. The other ones has the focus on being reverse proxies :)